# Infinite integrals involving derivatives of the spherical Bessel function

Tags: bessel-functions

I need to integrate

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\int dk\, k^2 j_\ell''(kr)j_\ell''(kr')
\end{equation}
Using
$$ j_\ell''(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}\bigg\{\big[\ell^2-\ell-z^2\big]\cdot j_\ell(z)+2z\cdot j_{\ell+1}(z)\bigg\} $$
I can rewrite the integral and split it in 9 terms. One of them is (up to a constant)

$$\int \frac{dk}{k^2}\, j_\ell(kr)j_\ell(kr') $$
which I don't know how to solve. I've tried using $j_\ell(z)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2z}}\cdot J_{\ell+1/2}(z)$ and looking up the resulting integral in Watson's book, I find a horrendous expression

[Watson's formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXf9T.png)

Is there a known solution to (1), or another way to solve it?